# После обновы до Polar Fox макет в студио стал размытым

Tags: android-studio

После обновления до Polar Fox макет у android studio стал размытым. Это можно как то исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слева три восклицательных знака в желтых треугольниках. Что там?

Comment: The item's text contrast ratio is 2.68. This ratio is based on an estimated foreground color of #9E9E9E and an estimated background color of #FFFFFF. Consider increasing this item's text contrast ratio to 3.00 or greater.

Comment: Это и есть про контрастность. Но я пока не знаю как её менять, в  гугле не могу найти пока. Но контрастность там плохая везде. И на кнопках и имейджах и т.п.